# Windows 10 gesture to switch between virtual desktops

Tags: windows-10-preview

Windows 10 introduces virtual desktops, some sort of equivalent of Mission Control on OS X. You can switch between the desktops using the Task view or using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>.

But I have been wondering if it is possible to **switch with touchpad gesture, with a three-fingers swipe** (like on OS X), which will be far more convenient. I don't think Microsoft will implement that before the release :(, it will probably need a tweak.

I have looked for some software to do that, but I haven't find anything. I tried to install a modded driver for my Synaptics touchpad in order to change the gestures' actions, but without success.

Does any of you have an idea about how to achieve that?

Comment: On the touchscreen you can swipe from left edge and then select the desired desktop

Comment: I think it's way to soon to ask for tweaks since there's no guarantee they will *not* implement a gesture for it (and of course any tweaks created for the Preview may break with the very next release).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Confirmed to work in the latest build of windows:

- Use 4 fingers on touchpad, place them gently on touchpad together and slightly move them to left or right; Which causes the virtual desktop to be switched.(like windows key + tab). Takes some time getting used to but in the end you will end up creating even more virtual desktops for yourself.
- Use 3 fingers on touchpad with same gesture to switch between apps(like alt + tab)

Remember though that in order for the new gestures to work, you have to install a windows 10 compatible touchpad driver, which is probably obtainable through windows update.

If not, you can manually update your touchpad driver via device manager(right click and press update)

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "latest build"? In the Insider program or just the latest windows updates?

Comment: At this time I'm not sure, the question has been answered 3 months ago so right now the windows update alone does it(tested yesterday)

Comment: Hmm weird, I run the latest W10 version ( not in insider ) and updated my I2C and PS2 Touchpad driver in the device manager via Windows Update and still can't use 4 finger swipe to change virtual desktops :( I tried original synaptics drivers, but OH MY GOD are they worse by a landslide in terms of precision and feel.

Comment: It seems that the synaptics touchpad driver is a little quirky, In order to make it work you also have to uninstall any touch pad drivers that were installed in your windows 8 era, then obtain the latest version(2016 version) through your laptop support site, or the synaptics download page. I guess searching about "Synaptics driver wipeout" with your laptop model inserted in the search term can help.

Comment: Latest build W10 with anniversary update, HP ProBook and it's working perfectly.

Comment: Can confirm, have run out of fingers.

Comment: I can also confirm this is NOT working with the latest WIndows update, after deleting my synaptics driver completely and using Windows update's driver

Comment: Wish I could give double points for this gem, superb!

Answer (score 5):

I recently wanted to figure out how to do this on my Lenovo Thinkpad L440, so I wrote an AutoHotkey script to do it. This should work on any laptop with a Synaptics touchpad: https://www.wptutor.io/misc/windows-virtual-desktop-swipe-gestures

Comment: Great script! I dropped it  in autostart and it does exactly what I needed on my Lenovo Yoga.

Comment: The link seems broken, I get a "Error establishing a database connection" error

Comment: Link broken. the 3 fingers gesture works on my Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro but not 4 and I have windows 10 1903.

Comment: The link is broken, but there is a a snapshot on the web archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20170707161121/http://www.wptutor.io/misc/windows-virtual-desktop-swipe-gestures

Answer (score 2):

I made a tool for this so that I didn't need to keep reaching for the keyboard when I was using vmware or some other program that ran on its own desktop, what it does is map keyboard keys to your touchpads 3 finger or 4 finger directional swipes, so you can map Ctrl+Windows+Left/Right to the left and right swipes to change desktops, I'll leave a link so that you can check it out and see if you like it.

[MultiSwipe](http://www.multiswipe.com/)

Comment: Error "No touchpad found" on Dell XPS 15 9550 (2016)

Comment: MultiSwipe (v3.2) works perfect. Windows 10 x64. Lenovo with ELAN Touchpad. Thanks for the app, you saved the day !

Comment: Works great on my Yoga 900!

Comment: Not working on DELL LATITUDE E6530

Comment: @modiX, check out my answer for Dell

Comment: unfortunately, I have MultiSwipe but no longer can use as no response from License error issues. The AutoHotkey and this have worked for me https://github.com/nullpo-head/Windows-10-Virtual-Desktop-Switching-Shortcut

Answer (score 1):

I have an asus laptop and use a program called "Asus Smart Gesture" which allows you to set a bunch of motion gestures on your touchpad. Using this, I found that swiping the touchpad with 4 fingers will switch between desktops. Try to download it for your computer at https://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/664/0/1/B54QCgYKVgEix639/CPUDRIVER_Ix-4xxxxU/41/

I don't know if it will work for you, but it did for me and I love it.

Answer (score 1):

On Dell laptops, open the Dell Touchpad program and enable Four Finger Swipe under Multi Finger Gestures:

[image]

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ul43blen6mx6hpx/dell_fail.PNG?dl=0 This is what it looks at me, and it does not work.