# Windows 10 finger gestures on touchscreen to switch between workspaces

Tags: windows-10, touchscreen

How can I switch between workspaces aka virtual desktops with my fingers on the touchscreen?

Clarification: Touchscreen gestures not Touchpad

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 10 gesture to switch between virtual desktops](https://superuser.com/questions/904910/windows-10-gesture-to-switch-between-virtual-desktops)

Comment: @MichaelBay I'm not talking about touchpad but touchscreen

Answer (score 0):

For touchscreen scenario, maybe AutoHotKey script is suitable.

https://github.com/pmb6tz/windows-desktop-switcher

https://github.com/searene/windows-desktop-switcher

Comment: If those links change or go dead this answer will become useless. Please include the relevant information from the link in the body of the answer, and include the link for reference.

Comment: I have a touchscreen display on my windows tabtop and I was talking about gestures with physically swiping on the screen with your fingers.